# configurable product name changes to simple product name when attributes (color/size) are selected

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, simple-product, magento-1.14

I have a configurable product for a shirt that has 150 simple products associated with it (30 colors, 5 sizes for each color). Today I noticed that the product name is defaulting to the name of the simple product once a color and size are selected. Can anyone tell me why the product name is changing from the configurable product name to the simple product name when a color and size are selected?

Incidentally, we also just applied an upgrade to Amasty Color Swatches Pro about a week ago, which we've also been having a separate set of issues with. I only mention this is in off chance that these two issues are related.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it is a configuration issue. In `system->configuration->Color Swatches Pro->Reload Product Information` is set to none.

Comment: Actually, for this field the following were selected: Name, Description, Short Description and Image. I deselected Name, Short Description and Description, since it should be the same as the configurable for every color. Thanks for putting me on the right track...MUCH APPRECIATED!